# Why JSP 2.0 Custom tag files are not working with Portlets?

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet, jsp-tags, liferay-6

I am trying to use JSP 2.0 tag files in my liferay 6.0 portlet application.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. My jsp is simple: `home.jsp`.

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

   <table>
       <tr>
           <td> <tags:tagDemo/> </td>
           <td><c:out value="Cout Hello"/></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. My tag file is ultra simple: `/WEB-INF/tags/tagDemo.tag`

   ```
   hello
   ```
3. `/WEB-INF/web.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-  app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

       <context-param>
           <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
       </context-param>

       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>view-servlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
   ```

This throws the following error:

```
00:14:42,642 ERROR [render_portlet_jsp:154] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: 55, column: 6) No tag "tagDemo" defined in tag library imported with prefix "tags"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1215)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this directive I think:`<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>`

It should be:`<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/tagDemo.tag" %>`

Also I have found a good tutorial for JSP 2.0 custom tags [here](http://www.softwaresummit.com/2005/speakers/BergmanJSP2.0TagFiles.pdf).

Comment: No. That wont work. We need not and should not metnion the actual tag name in the directive.

Comment: JSP 2.0 custom tags didnt work in liferay 6.0 portlet. But somehow they worked in liferay 5.x portlet.

Comment: That is strange it works in 5.x and not in 6.0. Hope you had the proper jar files for `jstl`. Secondly, why we `should not` mention the actual tag name? Any references? I have not tried yet but any reason or reference would be helpful.